# Package installation, rosdep cant find installation

Tags: rosdep, ros-kinetic, github, add-dependencies, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i want to install multiple packages for using a robot with ROS and have to build them out of source.

I created a worspace and cloned all repositories into the `src` folder. Then i ran `catkin_make` in the `catkin_ws` folder. I sources this directory with `source devel/setup.bash`. With `roslaunch` i can start the executables.
But one of this launch-files has problem with some dependencies.
I ran `rosdep check` on all the new packages and got this ERROR for every one of the new packages:

```
 Cannot locate rosdep definition for [...]
    rosdep key : ...
    OS name    : ubuntu
    OS version : xenial
    Data: <no data>
```

What did i do wrong while the installation. Do I have to put every new package to a new workspace?

---

Edit: I installed `innok_heros_description`, `innok_heros_control` and `innok_heros_gazebo`, then i found out, that i need `twist_mux` and installed it like the other packages. I cloned the repository in my workspaces `src` and `catkin_make`'d it. When i then ask for `rosdep check innok_heros_control` i get:

```
rosdep check innok_heros_control System dependencies have not been satisified:
  apt ros-kinetic-twist-mux
  apt ros-kinetic-joy
  apt ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-keyboard
  apt ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy
ERROR[innok_heros_control]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [innok_heros_gazebo] rosdep key : innok
```

Thanks for your help.
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288697/package-installation,-rosdep-cant-find-installation/) by [ich4913](https://answers.ros.org/users/34627/ich4913/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this a follow-up of #q288531?

> Do I have to put every new package to a new workspace?

No, that is not necessary. What makes you think that?

If `rosdep` can't find a *definition*, it basically means that the rosdep database does not contain a rule that maps a key to a (`deb`) package on your OS (Ubuntu Xenial in this case).

You could add the `-r` flag to your `rosdep install ..` command line, which makes `rosdep` ignore that dependency, but if it's actually needed, this will not solve your problem.

If `rosdep` can't find it, you'll have to figure out how to manually install that dependency. If you do, it might be nice to [contribute those rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) so future users can use `rosdep` to install that dependency.

---

Edit: as I wrote in #q288531, I would recommend you follow the procedure described in #q252478. In short, I'd recommend you run `rosdep check` as follows (where `$CATKIN_WS` is the path to your Catkin workspace):

```
rosdep check --from-paths $CATKIN_WS/src --ignore-src
```

That should tell you which dependencies are missing. As you already have `innok_heros_gazebo` in your `src` space, adding `--ignore-src` should make `rosdep` realise that it's already present.

Next, run `rosdep install` to have it install all dependencies needed:

```
rosdep install --from-paths $CATKIN_WS/src --ignore-src -y
```

Adding `-y` will avoid you having to acknowledge `apt`s confirmation prompts each time `rosdep` asks it to install a package.

If the author(s) of the Innok packages have used rosdep keys that don't actually exist, you could add `-r` to make `rosdep` continue in case it runs into a problem. Note that this may mean that things still won't entirely work (as you're still missing dependencies), but `rosdep` will then at least continue installing all dependencies it *does* know about / can resolve.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-15**:
Note: if you tell us which dependency this is, we could perhaps see what is going on.